# In a browser, is it possible to safely get a JSON resource from an external URL provided by the user?

Tags: javascript, browser, websecurity

I want to let users open my web app through a link that already contains the URL to the external resource. Then the web app needs to fetch this external resource and render content on the page based off of it.

This feature is important to me in order to allow users to integrate my app with their app or their own datasource.

Assuming my web app is hosted at example.com, a user needs to be able to open a link such as

```
https://example.com/view?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fexternal-hosting.net%2Ffile%2F24345
```

then based on this my code will

```js
const data = await fetch('https://external-hosting.net/file/24345')
const dataJSON = await data.json()
```

Is it possible to safely retrieve such JSON data directly in the browser, if there's no way to make sure that the URL can be trusted?

What security vulnerabilities does this introduce and can they be mitigated?

Comment: This is far too vague for a definitive answer to be provided. The default would be you can never fully trust user input. Explain your use case in more detail. Please also take some time to review what is and what isn't on topic here and how to properly ask questions. See [help]

Comment: @charlietfl I added an example, hopefully this clarifies it

Comment: well really all it does is create more questions about the validity of the url and what is returned from it and if it is CORS enabled and why you are needing to do this in the first place. You have greatly oversimplified an issue that can be full of  complexity

Comment: Yeah, your biggest problem will be CORS. Browsers usually don't let pages access other pages. Also if you could access those other sites, or had the server fetch them for you, there wouldn't be any real security vulnerabilities, unless you start adding information from that other website to your DOM, enabling XSS and such. Probably just use an <iFrame>.

Comment: As far as I know, JSON by itself would not be a serious threat unless you need to render the contents directly as HTML or evaluate in runtime. If the JSON contains only a representation of the data you need, you will just need to make sure that you will not use that data directly on `element.innerHTML` and similars or inside an `eval` function. I think that a search on Cross-Site Scripting and Remote Code Execution can help you with your question.

Comment: You would probably want to use a server to make the requests to the remote urls so you aren't CORS restricted and can validate content type headers, status and actual content with more granularity than you can using browser fetch()

Comment: @charlietfl the reason I want to do this is that I have a web app currently implemented as  a static site. It hosts a large amount of content and the content is fetched from different sources. Users edit small amounts of content at a time in github repositories. I want to create a tool that allows them to preview their changes without having to build and deploy the whole site and instead I want to allow simply displaying data from a JSON file. Users want the same feature also to be able to integrate this app with other apps.

Comment: @Giancarl021 thanks! There's no innerHTML or eval needed for my use case

Comment: @kantord You're welcome! Another small detail that I missed is that if you are setting attributes dynamically, this can be dangerous too. For example: if someone sends a JSON with a representation of an `<img>` without `src` but with the `onerror`  attribute, they will be able to run JavaScript on the client. One library that can help with that, if it is the case, is the [DOMPurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify).